# Whats the correct Build Options / Code signing / Scheme settings for profiling ui automation on a device?

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-automation

I'm trying to run with ui automation script on my my device / iPhone 4.

I've tried several settings without success and I'm not sure who I am anymore :(

**Build Options**

```
Validate Built Product: Ad Hoc - Yes, Debug - No, Release - Yes.
```

**Code Signing**

```
Ad Hoc - Entitlements.plist - can be debugged - no
Debug - Entitlement-Debug.plist - get-task-allow - yes
Release - Entitlements.plist - can be debugged - no
```

**Code Signing Identity**

```
Ad Hoc - iPhone Developer
Debug - Don't have set
Release - iPhone Distribution
```

**Profile Scheme**

```
Build Configuration - Release
Pre - Actions - None
Post - action - None
```

Obviously all of these settings may not be wrong, but I'd like some verification.

I've actually getting an error

```
The executable was signed with invalid entitlements
```

However, I don't think this is my only problem.

Comment: I've been doing some further reading to see if I can resolve this... Looking at http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation suggests that profile is performed on Release configuration and that the Developer Profile needs to be associated with it, I have distribution. Hmmm. Also that you don't need the elements files / therefore 'can be debugged = no' should be OK. Hmmm

Comment: Changing release - distribution to developer had no effect for me :(

Comment: Also changing scheme to Ad-hoc, has not effect. Begging to think this isn't my issue. I have tried a clean and my device is in my profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do UI Automation testing the bundle must be developer-signed. So you need to set the `iPhone Developer:` code-signing identity for your "Debug" configuration and use that configuration for UI Automation testing. Instruments needs to attach to your running process (i.e. it needs the `get-task-allow`) too, which is why you should use the Debug configuration in your case. Note that you could also create a new build configuration using the Release settings but including `get-task-allow`.

I highly recommend using the `accessibilityIdentifier` property on all your UI Elements to identify them, and using that to find elements in the UIA test scripts. That way your `accessibilityLabel` can still be used (and localised) for actual accessibility.

Comment: That works almost perfectly. Couple small issues, I saved my automation trace file when I used the simulator but this doesn't appear in my recent list. Just wondering if that indicates an issue? (I created another anyway). Also as I'm using "Debug" my "#ifndef NDEBUG" will be called, not really a true test, thoughts? On a totally unrelated note, which you don't need to answer, my reason for trying the device was due to a picker wheel date select value issue, have you seen a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure about the recent list. Since you only need the `get-task-allow` entitlement, you can create a new configuration if you want with the Release settings but including `get-task-allow` - that way you can ensure you're testing the release version without any Debug compile-time conditionals in there. I have found that in general UIA testing works better on the devices than on the simulator (simulator sometimes fails to update the elements list when searching for an element), so I recommend using devices where possible. I haven't used the date-picker wheel so not sure about that.